# Emacs org-mode imenu for tags?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, imenu

I'm new to org mode (not to emacs) and I'd like to change the behavior of Org when I click a tag. By default if clicking a tag, the agenda buffer appears. I don't use (and like) it, so I want to change that behavior: I'd like to have an imenu which appears if I click a tag that shows all headings which have this tag as well, so I can directly jump to a relevant heading.

This is how it looks in Tiddlywiki: [navigate by tag in tiddlywiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3GdJ.png).

I recently migrated from tiddlywiki to org-mode and I'm totally used to this. So it would be really great if someone could help me with that.

best regards,
Tom

Answer (score 2):

You can use `helm-org-in-buffer-headings` (from
[helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm)).

Or the more advanced `worf-goto` (from
[worf](https://github.com/abo-abo/worf)).  You can have a glimpse of
how it looks like in this
[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFTXnC1scno#t=1m19s).

In both cases, you don't click a tag, but enter it instead. Usually
just **:** and two-three letters are enough for a match.